# How to configure mongo converter in spring to encode all dots in the keys of map being saved in mongo db

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-mvc

In my spring project i have to save a map in mongo db ,Which is simple and i have done it. But then there a  problem occurred while saving this map in mongo db with a key as as string like **"N. Delhi"** . I tried to figure out and found that in mongo db **it is not allowed to save a map key with "." (dot) int because dot is have special meaning in mongo db.**

After few search i found that there is class in spring mongo driver named as **MonoMappingConverter** which have a method **setMapKeyDotReplacement** which could be used to encode all dots in mongo document before it save in mongodb and decode it back to dot while fetching. I tried but didn't found  right xml configuration of this converter with mongo template .

Can some one please let me know how correctly i could configure this converter in project or any other simplest way to save a map with dots in its keys in mongo.

Comment: As a general design point you probably should not be using named keys of a `Map` to begin with. Databases deal with "values" and not "keys". So what you think of as a `Map` is probably better stored as `{ "key": "N. Delhi", "value": 123 }` within an array instead. This will make querying and a whole host of operations far more natural than using "named keys".

Comment: @NeilLunn what you suggest is pretty good but problem is it is already implemented in a the way i mentioned and changing the existing implementation as whole might lead us to lost existing data which we don't want for sure. That's the reason i am looking for converters

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but are you not asking *"how to store with 'dot' or how to strip it?"*. Because my naive interpretation of that statement is that you actually don't yet have data at all. Hence the advice to correct the architecture thus avoiding that issue as well as the "future" issues of implementing "named keys" when you probably should not. My advice is therefore "don't do it" instead of looking for a way to support the translation.