# How can I ignore a "$" in a DocumentContent to save in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

My Problem is, that if I save a Document with a $ inside the content, Mongodb gives me an exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid BSON field name $ xxx

I would like that mongodb ignores the $ character in the content.

My Application is written in java. I read the content of the File and put it as a string into an object. After that the object will be saved with a MongoRepository class.

Someone has any ideas??

[Example content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQtUy.png)

Edit: I heard mongodb has the same problem wit dot. Our Springboot found i workaround with dot, but not for dollar.

[How to configure mongo converter in spring to encode all dots in the keys of map being saved in mongo db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46969868/how-to-configure-mongo-converter-in-spring-to-encode-all-dots-in-the-keys-of-map)

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Restrictions-on-Field-Names

Comment: What does your data look like? How are you attempting to save it?

Comment: i program everything in java. I created a own created object and read the content of a file with OCR to a string and add it to the object. After that i save the object with MongoRepository Class. Somehow the mongodb read the string with $ as a update operator command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Spring Boot you can extend MappingMongoConverter class and add override methods that do the escaping/unescaping.

```html
@Component
public class MappingMongoConverterCustom extends MappingMongoConverter {

    protected @Nullable
    String mapKeyDollarReplacemant = "characters_to_replace_dollar";

    protected @Nullable
    String mapKeyDotReplacement = "characters_to_replace_dot";

    public MappingMongoConverterCustom(DbRefResolver dbRefResolver, MappingContext<? extends MongoPersistentEntity<?>, MongoPersistentProperty> mappingContext) {
        super(dbRefResolver, mappingContext);
    }

    @Override
    protected String potentiallyEscapeMapKey(String source) {
        if (!source.contains(".") && !source.contains("$")) {
            return source;
        }

        if (mapKeyDotReplacement == null && mapKeyDollarReplacemant == null) {
            throw new MappingException(String.format(
                    "Map key %s contains dots or dollars but no replacement was configured! Make "
                            + "sure map keys don't contain dots or dollars in the first place or configure an appropriate replacement!",
                    source));
        }

        String result = source;
        if(result.contains(".")) {
            result = result.replaceAll("\\.", mapKeyDotReplacement);
        }
        if(result.contains("$")) {
            result = result.replaceAll("\\$", mapKeyDollarReplacemant);
        }
        
        //add any other replacements you need

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected String potentiallyUnescapeMapKey(String source) {
        String result = source;
        if(mapKeyDotReplacement != null) {
            result = result.replaceAll(mapKeyDotReplacement, "\\.");
        }
        if(mapKeyDollarReplacemant != null) {
            result = result.replaceAll(mapKeyDollarReplacemant, "\\$");
        }
        
         //add any other replacements you need
        return result;
    }
}
```

If you go with this approach make sure you override the default converter from AbstractMongoConfiguration like below:

```html
@Configuration
public class MongoConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration{

@Bean
public DbRefResolver getDbRefResolver() {
    return new DefaultDbRefResolver(mongoDbFactory());
}

@Bean
@Override
public MappingMongoConverter mappingMongoConverter() throws Exception {
    MappingMongoConverterCustom converter = new MappingMongoConverterCustom(getDbRefResolver(), mongoMappingContext());
    converter.setCustomConversions(customConversions());

    return converter;
}

   .... whatever you might need extra ...
}
```